# G Streamer pipeline not working properly

Tags: command-line, gstreamer

I've try the Below pipeline for Youtube Live straming...

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1' ! x264enc ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location="<You_Tube_URL>"
```

the pipeline closing suddenly in

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
```

Why ? What's the reason?

Comment: do you have a particular reason for using `gst` over `ffmpeg` other that you didn't know about `ffmpeg` ? https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/GStreamer-vs-FFmpeg-Pros-And-Cons-At-A-Glance

Comment: Split the pipeline and find out which element fails. For example, try a test source `videotestsrc` instead of camera source, or try `ximagesink` sink instead of sending to YouTube. Or maybe try a file sink to save the video to a file. You can also use a network traffic analyzer (Wireshark) to see if anything is sent over the network.